# input is int array, get all subsets

Tags: java, algorithm

I want get possible subsets, for example: input is {1, 2, 3}

expected result:

```
1
2
3
1,2
1,3
1,2,3
2,3
```

i use recursion to implement it, it think it is very slow, does it have more effective way?

Comment: Is it a programming contest ? Can you provide a link to the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), that can be solved in `O(n*SUM)`, where `SUM` is the sum of all number, using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

```
D(i,x) = D(i-1,x) OR D(i-1,x-arr[i])
D(0,0) = true
D(0,x) = false    x != 0
```

In here, `D(i,x)` gives a boolean value that indicates if sum `x` can be reached using some or all of the `i` first elements. Thus, for each possible sum `x`, `D(n,x)` indicates if this sum can be reached using any number.

Comment: i read the dynamic programming, still don't know how to write code. could you help me? we can chat on some im tool

Comment: but your comment is very helpful, now, i know i need find all subsets, then get them sum

Comment: i want use dynamic programming to find the answer, i hope you can give me some help which is how do i think about this question

Comment: @CarlXu Did you read the links I provided about Dynamic Programming and about Subset Sum Problem? Do you understand how to implement D(i,x) as recursive function in your favorite programming language?

Comment: that is so complex for me, can you provide some simple understand doc about DP

Comment: I can't understand it completely

Answer (score 1):

You could think about a recursive approach:

1. if you have only one number it is the only possible sum
2. if you have more than one number, than for each number:
   take the number it combined with all possible sums of the remaining numbers are also sums.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
allsums = makeAllSums(setOfNumbers){
  if(1==setOfNumbers.size)
    return setOfNumbers.head
  result = emptySet
  for(a in setOfNumbers)
    allSubSums=makeAllSums(setOfNumbers without a);
    for(b in allSubSums)
      result.add(a."+".b)
  return result 
}
```

Than you have only to think about avoiding duplicates.

Comment: yes, i also think about recursive, but "take the number it combined with all possible sums ", i don't how to do it

Comment: @Tony Zhai: I added pseudo code for a recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

Idea based on a binary number representation of the elements to add to a sum
from the initial set.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10
```

Every possible sum can be written as a 8 digit binary number where each digit stands for 'take this in the sum' of 'do not take this in the sum'.

Example:

```
001010100  means 3+5+7
111111111  means 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+9+10
000000001  means 10
010000000  means 2
```

So every possible sum can be written as a sequence of 0 and 1 of length 9.

All sums are all possible sequences of length 9.

So you can simply make a loop of the numbers 1 to 2^9-1 and interpret the binary representation as a sum.

```
000000001   : 10
000000010   : 9
000000011   : 9 + 10
000000100   : 7
000000101   : 7 + 10
...
111111111   : 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+9+10
```

This way you get all sums (no duplicates)

Comment: if a lots of number input sequence, is 8 digit binary enough?

Comment: @Tony Zhai Your example has 9 numbers so I used 9 digit binary value in my example. The number of bits must match the number of numbers in your input-set.